# grails GORM or statement

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

what I am trying to do is

```
Item.findAllByNameIlikeOrDescriptionIlike(search)
```

where search is a string.  It gives me the possible solution of

```
findAllByNameIlikeOrDescriptionIlike([Ljava.lang.Object;)
```

and throws the following error

```
Item.findAllByNameIlikeOrDescriptionIlike() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [f]
```

What is the correct way to try and achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grails doesn't know you want to use the same search parameter for both tests, it expects to see one argument for the NameIlike and a second argument for the DescriptionILike:

```
Item.findAllByNameIlikeOrDescriptionIlike(search, search)
```